# react native image background zoom

Tags: reactjs, react-native, zooming

I have a background image in my React Native application I want to add the ability to pan and zoom in/out.

Does anyone have a module that's worked well for them?

So far I've tried[image-pan-zoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-pan-zoom) and [photo-view](https://github.com/alwx/react-native-photo-view) but neither are working for me.

image-pan-zoom doesn't render my image properly because it doesn't appear to work well with flex.

photo-view doesn't appear to work with background images.

I'd like to be able to set a min and max zoom and ideally some other properties as well.  Below is a snippet of my code for the image I want to apply zoom to.

```
       <View style = {styles.Component2}>
            <ImageBackground
            source =  {require('/Users/bb/Coding/App/Images/Background.png')}
            style={styles.map}>
              <Animated.Image
                style={[
                  styles.pin,
                  {transform:
                    this.valuePin.getTranslateTransform(),
                    opacity: this.valuePino
                  }]}
                  source={require('/Users/bb/Coding/App/Images/cute')}/>
              <Animated.Image
                style={[
                  styles.bb,
                  {transform:
                    this.valueBus.getTranslateTransform(),
                    opacity: this.valueBuso
                  }]}
                  source={require('/Users/bb/Coding/App/Images/HB')}/>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to image background zooming ?